# MongoDB find all documents where property is not equals to another nested property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

here are my documents

```
  {
    "p1": {
      "lastName": "Manson"
    },
    "l1": [
      {
        "lastName": "Manson"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "p1": {
      "lastName": "revah"
    },
    "l1": [
      {
        "lastName": "Manson"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to get all documents where p1.lastName != l1.lastName

Should return:

{
"p1": {
"lastName": "revah"
},
"l1": [
{
"lastName": "Manson"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l1` is an array, hence it can contain more than one option.

If we want to find only document in which `p1.lastName` is different from all options in `l1.lastName`, we can use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$not: {$in: ["$p1.lastName", "$l1.lastName"]}}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - all options](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RTZUIR1sACs).

But if we can assume `l1` always contains only one item, we can use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$ne: ["$p1.lastName", {$first: "$l1.lastName"}]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - one option](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pKKGWxfvMo3).

The `$expr` allows comparing to values inside the document.